# Can't obtain inputstream

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I'm trying to work with the tess4j library, but I keep getting the error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract':
>   Can't obtain InputStream for linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271) at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398) at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:147) at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412) at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391) at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.(Unknown Source) at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source) at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source) at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source) at
>   net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source) at

I am trying to package the tesseract.so executable in my JAR. I saw the example here: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ and it seems to suggest I can just put it in my build path. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried building it against 32 and 64 bit JRE.

Comment: Which path through the tutorial are you taking?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. I found a precompiled version of libtesseract, so I'm not sure whether or not that's the problem. People seem to claim it's an issue with having the executable in the JAR file, but the tutorial specifically indicates you can do that. I tried both what I found to be the 32 and 64 bit of the executable. For more information, I'm working on SLES 11 64bit

Comment: You can set `jna.library.path` system property to the location of the `.so`.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more? What if it's in my JAR? At first it wasn't finding it, but when I put it in the build path, it's been "working" by giving me the above error as opposed to the one before it, "file not found"

Comment: So Linux SLES 11 64 and which tess4j version? Full stacktrace? Code example? To help you, others should have enough information in order to be able to reproduce the problem, don't you think?

Comment: I'm using tess4j 1.4.1. I'm just using their sample code so far. It's getting hung up on res = instance.doOCR(imageFile);

Comment: Are you serious? one call (instance.doOCR(imageFile)) that's it? Please edit your question with the full stack trace and the whole method you are using, so others _can_ reproduce it, thank you.